# how to receive a country code from google places in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I want to get the country code from the Google Places API but I can't figure out how.

```
if let addressComponents = place?.addressComponents {
   for addressComponent in addressComponents {
       print("Name: \(addressComponent.name) Type: \(addressComponent.type)")
   }
}
```

I always get results like that

```
Name: Sassnitzer Straße Type: route
Name: Lütten Klein Type: sublocality_level_1
Name: Rostock Type: locality
Name: Rostock Type: administrative_area_level_3
Name: Mecklenburg-Vorpommern Type: administrative_area_level_1
Name: Deutschland Type: country
Name: 18107 Type: postal_code
```

In the API you can set different filters for the autocompletion like `nofilter, geocode, address, establishment, region, city` Some of them give me additional results like `administrative_area_level_3` but no country code.

The idea is that the user enters his address and I just save the country code instead of the country name in different languages. 
In another programming languages the counrty code is the short name. For example like this `place.address_components[i].short_name`.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the country is not dependent of the programming language but rather dependent on the API. If you use the reverse geocoding API of google, you'll find in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) that setting the `result_type` to country should yield the results you're looking for. The results you printed earlier already contain the address_component saying `Deutschland`. That one has the `type` `country`. In that address component you should be able to find it in the `short_name`.

Comment: Hmm no I won't find `short_name` in the `address_component`. For the iOS SDK Google lists the supported types: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/supported_types#table2 It really seems that Google doesn't support this for iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get the country name and you can covert to country code

```
 if let addressComponents = place.addressComponents,let countryComponent = (addressComponents.filter { $0.type == "country" }.first) {
  let countryName = countryComponent.name
   print("Country::::::::\(countryName)")
}
```

Convert country name to country code

```
private func locale(for fullCountryName : String) -> String {

    for localeCode in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes {
        let identifier = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeCode)
        let countryName = identifier.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: localeCode)
        if fullCountryName.lowercased() == countryName?.lowercased() {
            return localeCode
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: This is the same thing what my for loop does. Your code filter for country. There is no convert. It's tricky (or just a lot of work) to convert a country name into a country. `Germany, Allemagne, Deutschland` has the country code `DE`. So Google already did this (in another frameworks). I don't want converting logic in my app.

Comment: i dont think u can directly get the country code from google places api.